# which one is more performance efficient in cluster environment, "Mobile agent" OR "Thread migration"?

Tags: java, multithreading, hazelcast, agent, agents-jade

I want to build a java based middleware application that can take client requests that are Runnable objects and execute the request in a minimum loaded node of the cluster. The client's request is a computation intensive task inside Runnable object, that is why I preferred a cluster environment as a target for my application. I want to build a highly scalable and fast server that can quickly respond to client's request. Which paradigm  should  Inchoose between mobile agent paradigm and client server paradigm. If client server paradigm is chosen then I will migrate the thread to minimum loaded node of cluster.  Is thread migration is more performance efficient over Agent mobility? Which one I prefer over other and why? What advantages I will have in Agent mobility over thread migration?

Answer (score 1):

You don't migrate a thread; you migrate the task (e.g. a runnable).

The correct solution really depends on your use case. With hazelcast it is easy to have your tasks executed within a cluster. Need more capacity? Add more members to the cluster.